# Regular Expression in Pig Latin

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I want to search for the string '15200' (without quotes) in tuples. So, for the following input:

```
15200
15200,4000
4000,15200
4000,15200,4025
152000
152000,4000
4000,152000
4000,152000,4025
115200
115200,4000
4000,115200
4000,115200,4025
```

The output should be :

```
15200,15200
15200,4000,15200
4000,15200,15200
4000,15200,4025,15200
152000,-1
152000,4000,-1
4000,152000,-1
4000,152000,4025,-1
115200,-1
115200,4000,-1
4000,115200,-1
4000,115200,4025,-1
```

My Pig code looks like this:

```
A = LOAD '/user/test'  USING PigStorage()  AS (logic:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE
logic,
((logic matches '(^|,)15200($|,)')? '15200' :'-1') AS expt;
```

But when I Dump B, I get:

```
(15200,15200)
(15200,4000,-1)
(4000,15200,-1)
(4000,15200,4025,-1)
(152000,-1)
(152000,4000,-1)
(4000,152000,-1)
(4000,152000,4025,-1)
(115200,-1)
(115200,4000,-1)
(4000,115200,-1)
(4000,115200,4025,-1)
```

Comment: Surprisingly, this works:

`B = FOREACH A GENERATE
logic,
((logic MATCHES '(^|.*,)15200($|,.*)')? '15200' :'-1') AS expt;
`

Comment: You can post your comment as an asnwer :)

Comment: It's not that surprising. It just means that the regex engine is looking for a match for the whole string, not an arbitrary substring. In which case you could use `'(.*,)?15200(,.*)?'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.*?\b15200\b.*
```

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/n6EP1s/2